# WebAPI: passing an array of objects using POST AJAX request (axios)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, axios

I am trying to pass data to a WebAPI route, but it is not binding - the parameter received is always null.

On the frontend, I have an array of jobs, similar to this:

```
const jobs = [{Id: 1, Name: 'First'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Second'}]
```

I am trying to pass this array to the backend, using a post request:

```
axios.post('jobs/insert', jobs, {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
```

This is the resulting raw request:

```
POST /api/job/insert HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 51
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.

[{"Id":1,"Name":"First"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Second"}]
```

On the backend side, I have this method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("insert")]
public IActionResult InsertJob([FromBody] List<dto.Job> jobs)
{
    return this.Ok(new { data = jobs });
}
```

The method is called correctly, but *jobs* is not binding correctly - it is always null.

This is the dto.Job model:

```
namespace Scheduling.Models.DTO
{   
    public class Job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried using `List<dto.Job>`, `dto.Job[]`, `IEnumerable<dto.Job>`. I also tried removing `[FromBody]`, or posting an object `{'': jobs}` instead of an array (as suggested on other websites). Nothing seems to work, for some reason the data received is always null.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Is the dto.Job from the Scheduling.Models.DTO namespace?

Comment: Yes, I have `using dto = Scheduling.Models.DTO;` in the controller

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the request body, the array is not json stringified

This

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"First"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Second"}]
```

Should be

```
"[{"Id":1,"Name":"First"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Second"}]"
```

In the axios request, try and stringify the object before sending it

```
axios.post('jobs/insert', JSON.stringify(jobs), {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
```

Comment: The exact same data is posted with or without JSON.strignify (this seems to be a quirk of axios). I tried forcing the body to be a string: `'"' + JSON.stringify(jobs) + '"'`, but still no luck

Comment: @Stratsys Great! It worked for me. However, I'm wondering why we should send string to a WebApi. I'd appreciate it if you could give me a reference to learn the reasoning behind that.